# Console into Google Cloud Build?

Tags: continuous-integration, devops, continuous-delivery, google-cloud-build

I'm using google cloud build to run tests for CI/CD. I've run into an error on my build and would like to console log into the running container to inspect the environment.

The error I'm receiving is from running "ng test" in an angular application. Karma gives me the error of:

> Step #1: 14 04 2019 12:00:01.869:ERROR [launcher]: No binary for
>   Chrome browser on your platform.
>   Step #1: Please, set "CHROME_BIN" env
>   variable.

So I want to be able to console into the environment so I can visually check and determine where the path to chrome bin may be.

For now the docs here state that I can only view the output history.

https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/view-build-results

Is it possible to console log into google cloud build? If so how can I console log into google cloud build?

Thanks

---

Update:

Thanks for the reply ffd03e.

Here is the yaml file I'm using now after adding your bash entypoint, along with the cloud output. I'll be looking into the links you have posted and make another update. (Since chrome ENV is empty, I had tried setting looking for it via ls) Although is this the only way to debug by using the YAML file? I'm hoping to remote into a bash shell in the cloud so I don't have to keep pushing changes to my repository just to log something.

Config and Output listed below:

```
steps:
# Install
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  args: ['install']
# bash -c | echo $CHROME_ENV - and checking chrome paths
- id: 'print env vars'
  name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/ng:latest'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
  - '-c'
  - |
    echo 'getting env'
    env
    echo 'NODE_VERSION: ' $$NODE_VERSION
    echo 'CHROME_ENV: '  $$CHROME_ENV
# Test - running this in root also runs test for libraries
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  args: ['run', 'test']
# Build
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  args: ['run', 'build']
# Deploy
- name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/firebase'
  args: ['deploy']
```

---

```
Starting Step #1 - "print env vars"
Step #1 - "print env vars": Pulling image: gcr.io/library-master/ng:latest
Step #1 - "print env vars": latest: Pulling from library-master/ng
Step #1 - "print env vars": 4b105072aa89: Already exists
Step #1 - "print env vars": b775667b1fd0: Already exists
Step #1 - "print env vars": 0fe156bcb4b1: Already exists
Step #1 - "print env vars": fb9906355a0f: Already exists
Step #1 - "print env vars": 880a3b83482f: Already exists
Step #1 - "print env vars": 228e101c8671: Already exists
Step #1 - "print env vars": f77ff8405034: Already exists
Step #1 - "print env vars": cd091f7b9743: Already exists
Step #1 - "print env vars": 60af6f0efde7: Pulling fs layer
Step #1 - "print env vars": 60af6f0efde7: Verifying Checksum
Step #1 - "print env vars": 60af6f0efde7: Download complete
Step #1 - "print env vars": 60af6f0efde7: Pull complete
Step #1 - "print env vars": Digest: sha256:2758958b0130229397599ce976ab163e8959ee2d1c4f13143d6c2233d792e79e
Step #1 - "print env vars": Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/library-master/ng:latest
Step #1 - "print env vars": getting env
Step #1 - "print env vars": NODE_VERSION=8.12.0
Step #1 - "print env vars": HOSTNAME=c2dc51ef6be7
Step #1 - "print env vars": PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
Step #1 - "print env vars": PWD=/workspace
Step #1 - "print env vars": SHLVL=1
Step #1 - "print env vars": HOME=/builder/home
Step #1 - "print env vars": YARN_VERSION=1.9.4
Step #1 - "print env vars": BUILDER_OUTPUT=/builder/outputs
Step #1 - "print env vars": _=/usr/bin/env
Step #1 - "print env vars": NODE_VERSION: 8.12.0
Step #1 - "print env vars": CHROME_ENV: 
Finished Step #1 - "print env vars"
Starting Step #2
Step #2: Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm
Step #2: 
Step #2: > library-master@0.0.0 test /workspace
Step #2: > ng test
Step #2: 
Step #2: 17 04 2019 13:32:21.481:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
Step #2: 17 04 2019 13:32:21.486:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v3.1.4 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
Step #2: 17 04 2019 13:32:21.487:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers Chrome with concurrency unlimited
Step #2: 17 04 2019 13:32:21.497:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
Step #2: 17 04 2019 13:32:21.498:ERROR [launcher]: No binary for Chrome browser on your platform.
Step #2: Please, set "CHROME_BIN" env variable.
Step #2: 17 04 2019 13:32:27.258:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
```

----------- Another Try using **ls** to find Chrome ---------

```
# Using 'ls' to look for chrome..
Step #1 - "print env vars": ls /usr/bin/google-chrome
Step #1 - "print env vars": ls: cannot access /usr/bin/google-chrome: No such file or directory
Step #1 - "print env vars": ls /usr/bin/chromium-browser
Step #1 - "print env vars": ls: cannot access /usr/bin/chromium-browser: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running `ng test` as a Build Step or in a Dockerfile?  It would be helpful to see your cloud build config.

Here is an example `cloudbuild.yaml` that prints environment variables. It also reproduces the error if used with `ng new my-app` and uses the [ng community cloud builder](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/ng).

```
# npm install
- id: 'install dependencies'
  name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  args: ['install']

# bash -c | echo $CHROME_ENV
- id: 'print env vars'
  name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/ng:latest'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
  - '-c'
  - |
    echo 'getting env'
    env
    echo 'NODE_VERSION: ' $$NODE_VERSION
    echo 'CHROME_ENV: '  $$CHROME_ENV

# ng test
- id: 'run unit tests'
  name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/ng:latest'
  args: ['test']
```

Resources: [Substitute Variable Values](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values), [Mastering Google Cloud Build Config Syntax](https://medium.com/@davidstanke/mastering-google-cloud-build-config-syntax-8c3024607daf)

It seems that your tests use chrome.  When running from Cloud Build, tests should be run using headless chrome or phantomjs.  The build step that you are running `ng test` might not have headless chrome installed.

Relevant links

- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2013
- https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-testing-with-headless-chrome-d1343b349699

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have updated the Question with the config and output.

Comment: how to add chrom_bin env or install chromeheadless?